# How Do I Fix Sound and Internet Connection on Ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I just loaded Ubuntu 9.04 to my computer. It runs great except:

1. It will not allow me to install the drivers from my cd that came with my intel motherboard (d945gclf)
2. No sound.
3. It will not connect to the internet. i.e. It will not show the setup wizard to run the setup program. I have tried globe wireless and smart bro. Can anyone tell me how to correct these problems?

Comment: And also fix his broken caps lock key...

Comment: Very funny ! Noted, you don't like CAPS LOCK...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I looked on the Intel website and the only linux driver they offer for downloading is a LAN driver, which means that probably most of the drivers that came on the CD are for Windows — so you wouldn't need to install them.

What I'd like you to check is if your network card is showing up. From a terminal window, type in

```
sudo ifconfig
```

and post the results. Let's first see if we can get you connected to the internet, then we can do an

```
sudo aptitude upgrade
```

and see what has to get fixed from there.

Comment: Will try that and get back to you later. got to set up the new computer first. Got mad and boxed it back up last night. Don't give on me, ok? i appreciate the help..

Answer (score 0):

What's your connection? If wireless you need **linux drivers**, not windows drivers. They are either already installed but not loaded or you need to install them (from ubuntu cd or download them on other computer from internet). My best guess is that wireless drivers just aren't loaded and/or you didn't choosed network to connect to ;). Are you on wireless and you just opened browser and hoped it would work? It won't work that way, you need to first connect to your network.

If it's not wireless it should work by default (especially if your ISP lets you use DHCP).